# C++ DevIL function ilLoadImage - program exit, access violation

Tags: c++, devil

I've got a path to my file defined this way:

```
const char* GROUND_TEXTURE_FILE = "objects/textures/grass.jpg";
```

And here is the function, which I use to load image:

```
bool loadTexImage2D(const string &fileName, GLenum target) {
    ...
    // this will load image data to the currently bound image
    // at first, we must convert fileName, for ascii, this method is fine?
    wstring file(fileName.begin(), fileName.end());

    if(ilLoadImage(file.c_str()) == IL_FALSE) { //here the program falls
```

What's wrong in my code? Why the program falls when `ilLoadImage` is called? I think, that `file.c_str()` should work fine as a `wchar_t *` type or not? Thanks for answer :)

Comment: I'm curious. Why use wchar at all? What happen if you load using fileName?

Comment: because const char * is incompatible with const wchar_t *  ... but I've figured it out ... the problem is not here, I did not initialize DevIl library using `ilInit();` ... my mistake

Answer (score 1):

As the author's said, you can do pretty anything without initializing the lib :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <IL/il.h>

int main ()
{
    std::string filename = "objects/textures/grass.jpg";

    ilInit();

    if (!ilLoadImage(filename.c_str())) {
        std::cout << ilGetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

build:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic --std=c++11 -g -o app main.cpp -lIL
```